# Get IAP original purchase date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, rmstore

I'm wondering if there's any way to get to the original purchase date of a consumable, non-recurring in-app purchase. The IAP's in my app are valid for 3 months. However, when a user deletes the app and then restores his purchase I can't find any way to get the original purchase date to see if the 3 months have passed. Any ideas?

```
[[RMStore defaultStore] restoreTransactionsOnSuccess:^(NSArray *transactions) {
    [[Game user] boughtFish];
    NSLog(@"Transactions restored");
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Something went wrong");
}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into the documentation and [source code](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore).

The success block of [restoreTransactionsOnSuccess](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/blob/master/RMStore/RMStore.m#L253) takes an array of *transactions*.
It comes naturally to the curious mind to ask for its reason for being.

It is [easily found](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/blob/master/RMStore/RMStore.m#L652) that the array is filled with objects of type **[SKPaymentTransaction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPaymentTransaction/transactionDate)**

One nice property of such class is `transactionDate` of type `NSDate`, which is what you want.

---

A simple proof of concept<sup>[compilation and test needed]</sup> is here

```
[[RMStore defaultStore] restoreTransactionsOnSuccess:^(NSArray* transactions) 
{
    NSLocale* dateLocale = [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale];

    for (SKPaymentTransaction* t in transactions)
        NSLog(@"%@", [t.transactionDate descriptionWithLocale: dateLocale]); 
} 
failure:^(NSError* error) 
{

}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You shouldn't rush to judgement. I've looked into this for quite some time before asking here. Maybe I've just looked in the wrong places.

Comment: @user4992124 True, sorry. I was being a jerk. Please accept my apologies. Happy coding and glad to help :)